# text overflowing and gives me a scroll bar under

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I have a problem: I am done creating a simple chat box using PHP, and my messages saves in my database, but whenever I type a very very long text, and PHP returns it to my page, my page will create a very long scroll bar to show all the text. What I've always wanted to is when I type a very long text, it automatically go down and will not create a scroll bar.

I want to show you a screen shot of my chatbox.

I already tried changing `width`s, `height`s and `nowrap`,
but still no luck in making it work.

This is shoutbox.php where shouts.php is included:

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db('try');

$submit=isset($_POST['sub']);

if ($submit)
{

    $message=$_POST['message'];
    mysql_select_db('try');
    $queryreg=mysql_query("INSERT INTO message(ID,message) VALUES('','$message')") or die (mysql_error());
}
?>

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="html/text"/>
    <style type="text/css">

        body
        {
            font-family:Tahoma;
            font-size:10pt;
            background-image:url(dota2background.jpg);
            -moz-background-size: cover;
            -webkit-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: top center !important;
            background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
            background-attachment: fixed;
        }
        #shouts
        {
            border:1px solid #000;
            width:1248px;

            white-space: nowrap;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <form action="shoutbox.php" method="post">
        <table border="1" width="1248" style="border:0;" cellpadding="5">
        <tr>
        <td><br/>Message:<textarea cols="50" rows="2" name="message" style="resize:none;"></textarea><input type="submit" name="sub" value="send">
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="1024px"><div id="shouts">
                <iframe name="shouts" src="shouts.php" width="1248px" height="720px" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
                </div>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <b>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is shouts.php:

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db('try');

$submit=isset($_POST['sub']);

if ($submit)
{

    $message=$_POST['message'];
    mysql_select_db('try');
    $queryreg=mysql_query("INSERT INTO message(ID,message) VALUES('','$message')") or die (mysql_error());
}
?>

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="html/text"/>
    <style type="text/css">

        body
        {
            font-family:Tahoma;
            font-size:10pt;
            background-image:url(dota2background.jpg);
            -moz-background-size: cover;
            -webkit-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: top center !important;
            background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
            background-attachment: fixed;
        }
        #shouts
        {
            border:1px solid #000;
            width:1248px;

            white-space: nowrap;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <form action="shoutbox.php" method="post">
        <table border="1" width="1248" style="border:0;" cellpadding="5">
        <tr>
        <td><br/>Message:<textarea cols="50" rows="2" name="message" style="resize:none;"></textarea><input type="submit" name="sub" value="send">
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="1024px"><div id="shouts">
                <iframe name="shouts" src="shouts.php" width="1248px" height="720px" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
                </div>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <b>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cant help unless you post some code...

Comment: done sir.. sorry, i forgot to post it. first time here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add 2 line of css to the place where you display the messages

```
.messages {
   float:  left;
   clear: left;
}

table{
   word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Check the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r0wcn3b1/

Comment: i tried this sir. but it did not work, it makes the border of each comments just turn left, but still text is overlapping.. but thanks sir for helping

Comment: @Hoodedwarlock are you displaying value in shout

Comment: it still overlaps sir. wait, i will upload a picture of it.

Comment: yes sir. everytime i send a message, shout.php will echo what is send

Comment: @Hoodedwarlock k , updated my answer, let me know if it works now

Comment: wow..!! thanks sir!! it worked!! hahaha.. Thank you very much sir.. hope i will help you someday..^^ i owe you one sir mohit..^^

Comment: No problem , you helped me by clicking the tick and marking it as answer